Bluetooth audio device connected and working but not listed by bluetoothctl
I'm using a bluetooth audio receiver called JR-CB1 to send my laptop's audio to my stereo. It has a strange issue where when it is connected, bluetoothctl is not aware of it. It is properly paired and everything, available as an audio sink in pipewire, and playing sound normally, but it is not shown in the list of connected bluetooth devices, neither in the Plasma bluetooth manager, nor when I run bluetooth devices Connected. It is the only device that has this issue.
It is only this way after I did a full system upgrade of my Arch system recently. Previously it, bizarrely, had the opposite issue: It was shown as connected by bluetoothctl but did not show up as an audio sink, and the device itself indicated it was not connected. But this only happened when I turned on the device and let it autoconnect. I used an udev rule to reconnect as a workaround.
The only reason it matter whether bluetoothctl is aware that the device is connected is that I use another udev rule to disconnect other connected audio devices when a bluetooth audio sink is added, to avoid signal interference. This doesn't work when bluetoothctl doesn't know a device is connected.
What could be going on here?
System:

Arch Linux
bluez 5.73-4
bluez-utils 5.73-4


Try the reasonably recent answers in this post.
